# Can I use common code snippets in PhpStorm 2019.1?

Tags: phpstorm, code-snippets

Are there any common code snippets (like for, foreach, if-else etc) in PhpStorm 2019.1 or any plugins that bring this functional? Seems weird not to have them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Please check [Live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/using-live-templates.html), **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, PHP**, for example.
You can use predefined templates or create your own, by either [saving your code snippets as templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html#730851f8) or creating templates manually in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates**.
See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/

Comment: Still can't find any plugins or anything with common snippets like function, simple for loop etc. It seems pretty strange to me that such great IDE doesn't have these things, because almost every text editor and IDE have at least plugins that bring in such snippets.

Comment: @ymdred16 I'm confused. Why exactly is the `for` loop provided by Live Templates unsuitable for you? What features do you have in mind for that yet to be written plugin?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález https://i.imgur.com/At4kQQ3.png These snippets were there from beginning, I have NOT edited anything. Can't see a for loop here (not foreach). Is something missing from here?

Comment: @ymdred16 Ah, right, I was thinking in `foreach`. Good old `for` is certainly not builtin, you must [add it yourself](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-creating-live-templates.html). Perhaps you can just copy the `fori` template from JavaScript. You also have [Postfix Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html), that's similar but different.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well that is what i'm talking about. A good php IDE lacks common snippets, while vs code, sublime and other things have plugins and built-in stuff for these purposes.